# PropertyGrid: remove a property of a custom data type only for a specific property

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, uitypeeditor

First: the wording of the question may be inaccurate, sorry for that. The actual question is below all code snippets.
Second: the code is in C#, but I usually write code in VB.NET.

I have a class `LabelData` which contains data for the visual appearence of a user drawn label. Short example:

```
public class LabelData
{
    public Color BackColor1 { get; set; }
    public Color BackColor2 { get; set; }
    public Color TextColor { get; set; }
    public int TextAngle { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

My `UserControl` draws a lot of text (lets call them small labels) using `LabelData`. It looks like this (simplified):

```
public class UserControl1
{
    public LabelData Title { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // draw title here

        LabelData currentLabel;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            currentLabel = new LabelData();
            currentLabel.BackColor1 = Color.Green;
            currentLabel.BackColor2 = Color.YellowGreen;
            currentLabel.TextAngle = 0;
            currentLabel.Text = "Element" + i.ToString();

            // draw text here
        }
    }
}
```

All data for the small labels are defined within `OnPaint`. I don't want this. I thought of a Template for the smaller labels like the `DataGridViewRowTemplate`. This also allows me to implement `ICloneable` for `LabelData`.

This would change to:

```
public class UserControl1
{
    public LabelData Title { get; set; }
    public LabelData LabelTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        LabelData currentLabel;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            currentLabel = LabelTemplate.Clone();
            currentLabel.Text = "Element" + i.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**Now the question**: How can I remove the `Text`-Property for the `LabelTemplate` property (but not for the `Title` property) in a `PropertyGrid` since this property changes in `OnPaint` anyways?

PS: I tried to create a custom designer and overwrite `PreFilterProperties` to remove the `Text` property, but I couldn't add a `DesignerAttribute` to the `LabelTemplate` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you probably will need an [ExpandableObjectConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter) to present properties assigned from your `LabelData` Class objects, you could create a Custom TypeConverter based on `ExpandableObjectConverter` and remove Properties from the base Class Object, when you want to present this object differently in specific circumstances.

Here, as example, while both **`Title`** and **`Template`** properties are shown as an expandable object in the PropertyGrid (so you can edit each property value with its specific type editor), the **`Template`** property has a slightly different Type Converter, where the  [`GetProperties()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.getproperties) method is overridden to remove the `Text` property from the underlying Class object, so it won't be shown in the PropertyGrid:

[image: Custom ExpandableObjectConverter]

<sub>The Template expandable object property doesn't show the Text property as its fellow Title property</sub>

**C# version**:

```
public class UserControl1
{
    public UserControl1() {
        Template = new LabelData() { ... };
        Title = new LabelData() { ... };
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public LabelData Title { get; set; }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(CustomExpandableConverter))]
    public LabelData Template { get; set; }

    // [...]
}

public class CustomExpandableConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    public CustomExpandableConverter() { }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var props = base.GetProperties(context, value, attributes)
                        .OfType<PropertyDescriptor>().Where(pd => pd.Name != "Text").ToArray();
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(props);
    }
}
```

**VB.Net version**:

```vb
Public Class UserControl1
    Public Sub New()
        Template = New LabelData()
        Title = New LabelData()
    End Sub

    <TypeConverter(GetType(ExpandableObjectConverter))>
    Public Property Title As LabelData

    <TypeConverter(GetType(CustomExpandableConverter))>
    Public Property Template As LabelData

    '[...]
End Class

Public Class CustomExpandableConverter
    Inherits ExpandableObjectConverter

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function GetProperties(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, value As Object, attributes() As Attribute) As PropertyDescriptorCollection
        Dim props = MyBase.GetProperties(context, value, attributes).
                           OfType(Of PropertyDescriptor)().
                           Where(Function(pd) Not pd.Name.Equals("Text")).ToArray()
        Return New PropertyDescriptorCollection(props)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: I didn't know you can filter them in a `TypeConverter`. This is great. I filtered some more properties, because there are actually much more in the `LabelData`class. Thank you very much.